\footfullcite not changing font size with new version of LaTeX
With the the 2023 version of LaTeX, the font size of footnotes with \footfullcite is larger than the font size of footnote, even if I use \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}.

Everything works well with LaTeX 2022.

Any idea about how to solve the problem?

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

You can avoid the problem by using the moloch theme instead of metropolis. It is an updated fork of metropolis which fixes a lot of problems:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  abc\footfullcite{knuth:ct}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


